# How hash id value in laravel collection all() method

Tags: php, laravel, bcrypt

I am trying to encrypt the id returned by the laravel all () method in my view.

my model

```
    protected $table = 'product';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_product', 'code_product', 'name','total_stock','id_category','id_brand'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_product';
```

I want to add something like bcrypt to the id_product column, since I use vue components in the request to the api that returns all the products, it is displayed decrypted before reaching the view and it would be useless to do it from there, that is why I am looking directly as an encryptor from here.

this the method of controller

```
    public function all(){
        return $this->successResponse(Product::with('category','brand')->get());
    }
```

any idea? thanks.

Comment: [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) maybe?

Comment: What effort have you made to do this work yourself?

Comment: I had tried an accessory but I was implementing it incorrectly to the attribute and it was not doing anything. But the colleague gave me the exact example, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 3 ways to handle  - not exposing the ids

**Option 1: Accessor & Mutator**

```php
class Product extends Model
{
     public function getIdProductAttribute($value)
    {
        return encrypt($value);
    }

    public function setIdProductAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['id_product'] = decrypt($value);
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Handle encryption/decryption in controller methods**

```php
public function all()
{
    return $this->successResponse(
        Product::with(['category', 'brand'])
            ->get()
            ->map(function($product){
                $product->id_product = encrypt($product->id_product);
                return $product;
            })
    );
}

//When you get the data back in say an update request handle decryption in the update method of controller
```

**Option 3: Use slug/uuid and hide the id from array**

Define a new column on the products table unique `slug` or a column to store `uuid` and then use this new column to uniquely identify the records in products table

And keep the id column in $hidden on the Product model class

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['id'];
}
```

Comment: amazing thanks, I did not know that just by writing the name of the method like that it recognized the attribute as in the first option thank you very much! and the third very good option had forgotten that attributes could be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Accessors and Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators) as a way to encrypt the value on the way out, and decrypt it on the way in. Then you can just use the [encryption helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption) inside those methods.